# What does this piece do that came with my disc brake?

Tags: disc-brake

I recently ordered [hydraulic Shimano disc brakes with rotors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OIG4NEG) and they came with a bunch of hardware, including this piece:
[image]

It looks like it would fit under the screws that secure the rotor to the hub:
[image]

Does anyone know what I should do with it or what its function is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These things are called tightening plates or lock washers. Your suggestion was righ in where it goes, here's an exploded diagram and [installed photo](http://endurama.de/fotos/galerie/shimano_zee_sm_rt66_bremsscheibe.jpg):
[image]

Comment: It seems the OP is missing two of them then (the photo shows three) as well as the flange.

Comment: I guess he'll have to contact the seller in this case.

Comment: These are brand new disc brakes that I installed myself. I have 6 of those pieces, 3 for each disc brake. I just wan't sure what it was, so I showed one of them in the photo. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can a source for the exploded view be provided?

Comment: I just found it on mtbr using image search. Judging by overall style, it looks like a screenshot from one of Shimano PDF docs, but I don't know which one.

Comment: @LopSae Official Shimano exploded views: [Rear Disc Brake](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-BR-M395-R-3268.pdf). [Front Disc Brake](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-BR-M395-F-3356.pdf)